# Open single instance of form editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have Form Editor and on every double click event on editor input I need to avoid duplicate instance of the form editor to open. I'm setting the editor name by `setPartName`
I need to check that name and to be open only one instance

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Are you saying you only want one instance of the editor open regardless of what file they user tries to edit?

Comment: My editor name will set dynamically, and i want only one instance of the editor open for each name... For ex:   first time if i open the editor with myEditor next time it should not open the efitor for same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a `matchingStrategy` class in your `org.eclipse.ui.editors` definition of the editor which lets you control which editor is used to open files,

For example this is the definition of the PDE plugin.xml/MANIFEST.MF/build.properties editor:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
        default="true"
        name="%editors.pluginManifest.name"
        icon="$nl$/icons/obj16/plugin_mf_obj.png"
        class="org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.plugin.ManifestEditor"
        contributorClass="org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.plugin.ManifestEditorContributor"
        matchingStrategy="org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.plugin.ManifestEditorMatchingStrategy"
        id="org.eclipse.pde.ui.manifestEditor">
        <contentTypeBinding contentTypeId="org.eclipse.pde.pluginManifest"/>
        <contentTypeBinding contentTypeId="org.eclipse.pde.fragmentManifest"/>
        <contentTypeBinding contentTypeId="org.eclipse.pde.bundleManifest"/>            
  </editor>
```

The matchingStrategy`class must implement`IEditorMatchingStrategy` which has one method:

```java
public boolean matches(IEditorReference editorRef, IEditorInput input)
```

> Returns whether the editor represented by the given editor reference
>   matches the given editor input.
>
> Implementations should inspect the given editor input first, and try
>   to reject it early before calling IEditorReference.getEditorInput(),
>   since that method may be expensive.